# Infinite loop using useEffect hook on react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I'm having a weird behavior with my useEffect, on ReactJS. I use this for a "componentDidMount" event:

```
index.js from Home

  useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isAuthenticated)
        dispatch(Actions.checkIfTokenHasExpired());
    }, []);
```

The problem is that on react-native it starts a infinity loop, recreating the component all the time. Does useEffect works differently in RN? If so how can I fix it?

Also I realized that the loop just happen if inside my action I return a function, like this:

```
actions.js

export function checkIfTokenHasExpired() {
  return async dispatch => {
        try {

            dispatch(showLoader(true));

            await Api({ accessToken: helper.accessToken }).post('account/check_if_token_has_expired', { /*body*/ });

             dispatch({
                 type: Types.CHECK_IF_TOKEN_HAS_EXPIRED,
                 isAuthenticated: true
             });

        } catch (err) {

            dispatch(handleActionError(err));
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: App structure:

```
App.js
|   src
|   |   index.js
|   |   |
|   |   actions
|   |   |   index.js
|   |   components
|   |   |   screens
|   |   |   |   Home
|   |   |   |   |   index.js
```

EDIT²: JSX of index.js from Home.js:

```
export default function Home(props) {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector(state => state.auth);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(Actions.checkIfTokenHasExpired());
    }, []);

return (
   <View>
      <BigLogo source={logo} />{/*a simple styledComponent with ImageBackground*/}

      <LoginCard {...props} />{/*a login panel*/}
   </View>
)
```

Comment: please provide more context on this: the tree structure of your components, it's hard to figure out what's causing the component to be recreated.

Comment: i did not mean the file structure. i mean the jsx structure (html like).

Comment: updated main post

Comment: Do you intend to check if token has expired only when render home screen?

Comment: @JoseRojas only once at the start of the app, on create and never again.

Comment: I suspect your token checking function is updating state higher up the tree which then causes a re-render and maybe even a re-mount of your Home component. Try returning a function that logs "Home.unmounted" from your useEffect, then you can see when it's being unmounted.

Comment: @BenjaminGodlove you're right man! Inside the first index.js from my app structure there's a useSelector calling a state from redux store:
`const { showLoader } = useSelector(state => state.utils);`
This is making the home update itself. Now I must learn how can I prevent this to happen. I really need this loader to be on higher up in the tree cause I use two stackNavigators, one for the screens and another for the modals. This <Loader /> needs to be there. Thanks for the help anyway.